# How to get the right UTC Timestamp in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, utc

I am trying to calculate the Unix Timestamp in milliseconds or seconds in C#.
I know this question has been asked several times, but all solutions i could found won't help me.

I calculate the UTC Timestamp in milliseconds like this:

```
DateTime sTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
this.startTime = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - sTime).TotalMilliseconds;
```

The result of this calculation is: 1430555363795 but the correct milliseconds of the unix timestamp are: 1430572772661. I don't understand what i am doing wrong.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you know it's been asked before, you should explain *why* the existing answers don't help you. When did you run that code? That exact code works fine for me... perhaps your system clock is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you set an incorrect timezone, perhaps your clock is wrong or perhaps your supposedly "correct" value is wrong.

Comment: i use `(DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTimeUtc()-0x19db1ded53e8000)/10000` for this

Comment: I try to get this utc time in milliseconds: http://currentmillis.com